In dotnet, how do I handle self-signed certificates AND certificates from well-known CA WITHOUT adding to "Trusted Root Certification Authorities"
In dotnet, how do I handle self-signed certificates AND certificates from well-known CA WITHOUT adding to "Trusted Root Certification Authorities"?
I've been referring to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/working-with-certificates
Using a CustomTrustStore with CustomRootTrust will mean that certs from a well-known CA will not work (right?)
    var chain = new X509Chain();
    chain.ChainPolicy.CustomTrustStore.Add(rootCaCertificate);
    chain.ChainPolicy.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.Online;
    chain.ChainPolicy.TrustMode = X509ChainTrustMode.CustomRootTrust;
    bool success = chain.Build(endUserCertificate);

Using a CustomTrustStore with CustomRootTrust will mean that certs from a well-known CA will not work (right?)
    var chain = new X509Chain();
    chain.ChainPolicy.TrustMode = X509ChainTrustMode.CustomRootTrust;
    chain.ChainPolicy.CustomTrustStore.Add(rootCaCertificate);
    chain.ChainPolicy.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck;    
    bool success = chain.Build(endUserCertificate);

-> Certificate is valid, but certs from well-known CA cannot be verified against the CustomTrustStore (I think).

And adding the (self-signed) root to ExtraStore cert will fail as the (self-signed) root ca is not trusted.
    var chain = new X509Chain();
    chain.ChainPolicy.ExtraStore.Add(rootCaCertificate);
    chain.ChainPolicy.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck;    
    bool success = chain.Build(endUserCertificate);

-> UntrustedRoot: The certificate was not trusted.


Is there some way to accomplish this without modifying the system "Trusted Root Certification Authorities"?  I suppose if the certs in the system trust store were available, they could all be added to the CustomTrustStore.
Thanks in advance.
Mike

No, X509Chain just isn't built to handle this, it can only deal with a single root store. See this GitHub issue.
But adding a custom root certificate to the system store is often impossible if you aren't an admin.
Your alternatives are:

Getting all system root certificates and adding them to the custom store.

var chain = new X509Chain();
chain.ChainPolicy.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.Online;
chain.ChainPolicy.TrustMode = X509ChainTrustMode.CustomRootTrust;

using (var machineStore = new X509Store(StoreName.CertificateAuthority, StoreLocation.LocalMachine, OpenFlags.ReadOnly))
using (var userStore = new X509Store(StoreName.CertificateAuthority, StoreLocation.CurrentUser, OpenFlags.ReadOnly))
{
    chain.ChainPolicy.CustomTrustStore.AddRange(machineStore.Certificates);
    chain.ChainPolicy.CustomTrustStore.AddRange(userStore.Certificates);
    var success = chain.Build(endUserCertificate);
}


Building the chain twice. For example:

var chain = new X509Chain();
chain.ChainPolicy.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.Online;
var success = chain.Build(endUserCertificate);
if (!success && chain.ChainStatus.First().Status == X509ChainStatusFlags.UntrustedRoot)
{
    chain.ChainPolicy.CustomTrustStore.Add(rootCaCertificate);
    chain.ChainPolicy.TrustMode = X509ChainTrustMode.CustomRootTrust;
    success = chain.Build(endUserCertificate);
}


How can one "Get all system root certificates"?  I tried to ask that in my question.
I will try "building the chain twice".  Thank you for your answer.

This seems to work:
var chain = new X509Chain();
chain.ChainPolicy.ExtraStore.Add(rootCaCertificate);
chain.ChainPolicy.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck;
var success = chain.Build(endUserCertificate);
if (!success && chain.ChainStatus.First().Status == 
X509ChainStatusFlags.UntrustedRoot)
{
    chain.ChainPolicy.CustomTrustStore.Add(rootCaCertificate);
    chain.ChainPolicy.TrustMode = X509ChainTrustMode.CustomRootTrust;
    success = chain.Build(endUserCertificate);
}
var errors = chain.ChainStatus.ToList();


How is that different from my answer?

Yes - it's the same.  When I first posted that, I was running in a standalone application and was getting PartialChain instead of UntrustedRoot, and I posted to show the difference.  But when I put that in my actual application that gets chain as an argument,  instead of PartialChain I was getting UntrustedRoot (because the self-signed root CA cert was already in the chain - I guess there is something in the application that was inserting it?). I've inherited this piece of code to fix and am unfamiliar with the scaffolding.
